# Is the code thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have looked through some questions about this snippet on StackOverflow, but none of them mentions the problem I found out.

Here's the code:

```
@immutable // This is not a standard annotation .Only for Showing that behavior of Class 
class OneValueCached{
    private final BigInteger lastNumber;
    private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    public OneValueCached(BigInteger i,BigInteger[] factors){
        lastNumber=i;
        lastFactors=Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
    }

    public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i){
        if(lastNumber==null || !lastNumber.equals(i))   // ---> line 2
            return null;
        else 
            return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);   // ---> line 3
    }
}

@threadSafe // This is not a standard annotation .Only for Showing that behavior of Class 
public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet{
    private volatile OneValueCached cache=new OneValueCached(null, null);

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponce resp){
        BigInteger i= extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors=cache.getFactors(i);   // ---> line 1
        if(factors==null){
            factors=factor(i);
            cache=new OneValueCached(i, factors);   // ---> line 4
        }

        encodeIntoResponse(resp,factors);
    }
}
```

Imagine,

Thread A comes to line 1, and invokes `cache.getFators(BigInteger i)`, and it comes to line 2, the condition statement return *false*.

Then Thread B comes to line 1, and also invokes `cache.getFators(BigInteger i)`, when it comes to line 2, the condition statement return *true*. So Thread B continues, and comes to line 4, changes variable `cache` to a new one.

Thread A continues, and comes to line 3, returns a WRONG result!

So what's wrong? Is this code thread-safe? (According to the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*, yes, it is thread-safe)

update:

I am thinking about that when Thread B changes the value of `cache` to a new one, the Thread may still return the copy of of lastFactors of previous object. Am I right?

Comment: Looks like the worst-case behavior is that it calculates twice, but the calculation is idempotent.

Comment: *The cache-related operations cannot interfere with each other because OneValueCacheis immutable and the cache field is accessed only once in each of the relevant code paths. This combination of an immutable holder object for multiple state variables related by an invariant, and a volatile reference used to ensure its timely visibility, allows VolatileCachedFactorizer to be thread-safe even though it does no explicit locking.* @hyd

Comment: Btw, you can use `factors.clone()` instead of `Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this code is thread safe.

Since `OneValueCached` is immutable, an instance of it can never return a wrong result, assuming it was constructed with right values. Either it returns correct result, or it returns `null`.

When cached value is changed, the `cache` variable changes atomically, because it is `volatile`. It might be that at certain time there are two `OneValueCached` instances used: method for one instance is called, then executing thread changes, a new instance is created and `cache` reference is changed to point to a new instance, but it doesn't affect the other thread and the old instance, which won't be eligible for garbage collection until the method call returns (`this` variable in the executing method keeps it alive).

Furhtermore, there is no special efficiency penalty for storing unnecessary instances in `cache`, because the instances need to be created anyway, and actually storing the reference in `cache` is inconsequential from performance point of view. Different way to implement caching (for example being able to store multiple values) could improve performance further, but doing it like this is still no worse (difference in memory use pattern is inconsequential) than not caching at all, even in the worst case (cached values never used).

Comment: This answer should start with "Yes, this code is thread-safe"

Comment: @user2916610, this is an optimization technique called "memoization".  It's googlable